# Why for loop does not take 0 into account in sequence from negative to positive values?

Tags: r, for-loop

```
result <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 32,nrow = 61))
colnames(result) <- c("Age","y_1990", "y_1991", "y_1992", "y_1993","y_1994" ,"y_1995", "y_1996",
                      "y_1997", "y_1998", "y_1999", "y_2000", "y_2001", "y_2002", "y_2003", "y_2004", "y_2005",
                      "y_2006" ,"y_2007", "y_2008", "y_2009" ,"y_2010", "y_2011", "y_2012", "y_2013" ,"y_2014",
                      "y_2015", "y_2016", "y_2017", "y_2018", "y_2019", "y_2020")






for(i in 2:ncol(result)) {       
  for (a in -1:59){
    result[a,1]=a
    #result[a,i] = length(which(data[,i+1]==a))
  }
}
```

Here I create a new data frame with empty cells. I want to fill the first ("Age") column from -1 to 59 including 0. However, the results do not include 0 for some reason and include two -1s instead. Any help would be appreciated.

The results below(Age column):

```
    Age y_1990  y_1991
56  56  0   0
57  57  0   0
58  58  0   0
59  59  0   0
60  -1  0   0
61  -1  0   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `result` is a dataframe.  Dataframes are indexed from 1 to n, where n is the number of rows in the dataframe.  In your code you cannot set a negative index for the row.  One way to solve your problem would be:

```
result <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 32,nrow = 61))
colnames(result) <- c("Age","y_1990", "y_1991", "y_1992", "y_1993","y_1994" ,"y_1995", "y_1996",
                      "y_1997", "y_1998", "y_1999", "y_2000", "y_2001", "y_2002", "y_2003", "y_2004", "y_2005",
                      "y_2006" ,"y_2007", "y_2008", "y_2009" ,"y_2010", "y_2011", "y_2012", "y_2013" ,"y_2014",
                      "y_2015", "y_2016", "y_2017", "y_2018", "y_2019", "y_2020")
result[,"Age"] = -1:59
result$Age # This should display -1 0 1 2
```

In the above code `result[,"Age"] = -1:59` sets the whole `Age` column to -1:59.

Doing it this way is also a little more compact than using a for loop.

Comment: Oh OK, I got it. Thank you!

Comment: if you think the solution helped you, you can mark this response as the answer. I'm glad it helped.